# Problems driving electromagnetic mirror

Tags: electromagnetic, mirror

**EDIT: The question was completely edited because the major problem - overloading - was solved. One of the units in the OpAmp was damaged, so it was malfunctioning when connected to the load.**

Currently, I use a function generator and a simple voltage divider to create a required signal to drive a galvo-mirror (no datasheet available, the coil resistance was measured 16-17 Ohms). The circuit below works, but it is oversimplified, and I believe, there should be additional circuitry to stabilize, protect, etc. the circuit.

[image: My simplified circuit]

The other problem is that my signal is derived from DAC and comes out as a saw tooth wave ranging 0-5V (see the schematic below). Scaling the output of the DAC to feed into the [OpAmp](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8531_8532_8534.pdf) is not a big deal - I use a trimmer R1 to make the wave range from 0 to 1.6V. The next step is to offset the wave to the same voltage as the other input (in this case +2.5VDC):

[image]

- What are the additional components that should be introduced to the circuit, excluding bypass capacitors, that would ensure proper/better performance of the circuit.
- What would be a good way to offset the voltage between R1 and the OpAmp input **without** introducing any additional active components (transistors, OpAmps...)
- The principal schematic would be appreciated.

It seems trivial to simply provide 0-1.6V wave to input1 and provide 0.8VDC to the second input of the amplifier, and no deed in offsetting the wave. However, it makes the signal to slightly rail out, so I prefer to run the voltages in the midrange at 2.5V.

Comment: It is not a good practice to add capacitance to op-amp output because you may compromise stability.

Comment: What is the maximum frequency the mirror will respond to or that you care it responds to?  Also how much current (or voltage) does it take for full deflection?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I hope I measured correctly: 40mA AC at saw tooth 3Vp-p, and 50mA at 1.5VDC. The **saw tooth** frequency will be about 5Hz, maybe 10Hz in the future. There will be a small delay when transitioning abruptly from the top of the ramp to the bottom to stabilize the mirror.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful information.  I don't have time for a good answer now, but maybe tomorrow.

Comment: There is a DIY project that includes the following circuit to drive a similar galvo mirror.  The developer has found out, as others before him, that for any kind of efficiency and speed a closed loop system is selected, for slow speeds open loop may suffice. You may get some ideas of the drive components that he used though he mentions that there are superior parts available. http://elm-chan.org/works/vlp/g/galamp2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would attack this as a control problem.  No doubt the actual mirror position lags the current or voltage the unit is being driven with, and may have overshoots or ringing, depending on how the system as a whole is compensated.

I would try to do as little in analog as possible.  For something this slow (10 Hz response), you can easily close the loop or generate the control signal in a microcontroller digitally.  The analog drive signal is then produced by low pass filtered PWM from the micro.  You can have the processor produce two complenentary PWM streams, or one stream that you invert externally.  Low pass filtering these yields the positive and negative analog drive signals, which you buffer with the amps you have, since they seem to be working.  At this low power, you don't have to worry about effeciency unless this is battery operated.  I that case I'd use a class D audio amp chip to create the drive to the deflection coil.

Even with modest PWM clock frequency you have plenty of resolution left and lots of room between your highest frequency of interest and the PWM frequency to allow for simple analog filtering.  Let's say the PWM clock is 10 MHz to be conservative (you can easily get micros that are capable of much higher), and that 256 levels is good enough.  That means the PWM frequency will be 39 kHz.  Two poles of RC filtering at 100 Hz would attenutate the PWM frequency by 150k, which eliminates it for practical purposes.  That still leaves plenty of headroom above your fastest desired response frequency, which is 10 Hz.

Having a digital processor in there allows for some computations on the setpoint to produce the control output that the coil is driven with.  If you have position feedback, then you can completely close the loop.  However, even without that you can mix the setpoint and it's derivative at the right proportions to get some feed-forward.

Generally you want to run the control loop 20-50 times faster than the period of the highest frequency of interest.  Even 500 Hz control loop iteration is 2 ms, which is a long time for something like a dsPIC.  That's slow enough you could even do a arbitrary convolution of the set input against a fixed function to make the control output, so just about anything is possible.

Another advantage of a micro is that it can receive commands digitally, which may be how you receive them (that's the case more and more nowadays).  If not, then you present the setpoint input the A/D of the micro.  I'd read that maybe every 10 µs or so and apply some low pass filtering to reduce noise, then the current filtered value gets grabbed at the beginning of each 2 ms control iteration.  I have done exactly that several times, with plenty of cycles left over on a dsPIC.

Comment: I did not think about PWM because I never used it before and do not know anything about it, unfortunately. The mirror should be deflected discretely, not continuously. I provide 0-1024 digital input to the DAC, which gives me a 1024 "stairs" ramp from 0 to 5V. Thus my mirror starts from the maximum deflection from one side and rotates in 1024 steps to the other maximum. If I wanted to stick to the current analog design, is there any additional recommended circuitry, that should be introduced to the circuit above? I might consider PWM, but first, I must learn about it.

Answer (score 3):

Note that my answer, below, pointed out defficiences in the question's original circuit.

Your op-amp has no negative rail and your signals, power and feedback use 0V as the reference voltage. This will mean your output will be a 5 Hz sinewave half wave rectified. Try creating a -12 v rail OR bias up your signal and feedback grounding resistors to midrail between positive supply and ground.

I can see that your 2nd op-amp is making an attempt to use a centre rail but R6 needs to connect to that rail as does R5 and the signal ground.

Also, LM358s are not noted for their ability to drive electromechanical loads so I'd consider using something more appropriate and powerful.

Comment: I just made a small edit to the question. I guess I need a 8Vp-p wave, and I believe it does not have to be -4V to 4V. Since I am trying to use the two outputs as the differential signal, wouldn't the 0-8V and +4V make a fluctuating wave from 0 to 8V around 4V offset?

Comment: If the output from the DAC is 0 to +5V then the output from the top op-amp will be 0 to +10V but I don't think the output will swing up to +10V from a 12v supply. It might get to 8 v swing though BUT will it drive an electromechanical load? I don't think so. It's probably only capable of driving 40mA.

Comment: I just tried [AD8532](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8531_8532_8534.pdf) amplifier. It's a 250mA 5V rail-to-rail dual OpAmp. Both OpAmps are configured as buffers G=1. First one gets 0-5V wave, the second one get's 2.5VDC. When I connect the mirror, the circuit does not seem to work in "differential" mode - the mirror deflects more to the one side than the other. Flipping connectors changes the deflection pattern. But the mirror still does not deflect evenly to both sides. When I measure A-B math on the oscilloscope, I get a perfect -2.5V to 2.5V signal.

Comment: The AD8532 is now probably damaged because it's only meant for a maximum supply voltage of 6 volts and has an AMR of 7 volts

Comment: The original circuit uses this OpAmp as well. But they use some tricks to make it work. I tried to reproduce the voltage from the original board, but the mirror does not perform as it should. See edits.

Comment: @Naz can you be absolutely clear in what you need to drive in terms of voltages and peak current levels. Also can you indicate what power supplies you have available to achieve this.

Comment: If I measured correctly: 40mA at saw tooth 3Vp-p AC, and 50mA at 1.5VDC. The saw tooth frequency will be about 5Hz. Using 3Amps bench top power supply, later, [LM1085ISX-5.0/NOPB](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1085.pdf)